# Jovian DSA Binary Search problem running an infinite loop when I tried to code for finding 1st occurrance of the query

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, jupyter-notebook, binary-search

My doubt is on Lesson-1 of Data Structures and Algorithms in Python of Jovian.ai [see my execution in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rGTD.png),
In Binary Search of Cards, I thought of implementing the recursion technique(in repeated occurrance of query test case) but its not executing and I also tried executing using While loop but it has also failed. (Failed in this context refers to continuous running without output (infinite loop))

Can you please explain me the failure reason so I can eradicate in future problems.
Please find my code in attached Image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please also include the code in post, not the image, so people can check it out easily.